# Pull fields/attributes from lsof (Linux command line)

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, flv

With the recent move to Flash 10 (or maybe it was a distro choice), I and many others are no longer able to copy Flash videos from /tmp. I have, however, found a workaround in the following:

First, execute:

```
lsof | grep Flash
```

which should return output like this:

```
plugin-co 8935    richard   16w      REG        8,1   4139180       8220 /tmp/FlashXXq4KyOZ (deleted)
```

Note: You can see the problem here....the /tmp file has the file pointer released.

You are, however, able to grab the file by using the cp command thusly:

```
cp /proc/#/fd/# video.flv
```

where the 1st # is the process ID (8935) and the second if the next number (16, from 16w).

Currently, this works, but it requires a few manual steps. To automate this, I figure I could pull the PID and the fd number and insert them dynamically into the cp command.

My question is how do I pull the appropriate fields into variables? I know you can use $1, etc. for grabbing input arguments, but how do you retrieve outputs?

Note: I could use `pidof plugin-container` to find the PID, but I still need the other number (since it tells which specific flash video to save).

Answer (score 5):

The following command will return PIDs and FDs for all the files in `/tmp` that have filenames that begin with "Flash"

```
lsof -F pfn /tmp/Flash*
```

and the output will look something like this:

```
p16471
f16
n/tmp/FlashXXq4KyOZ
f17
n/tmp/FlashXXq4KyOZ
p26588
f16
n/tmp/FlashYYh3JwIW
f17
```

Where the field identifiers are p: PID, f: FD, n: NAME. The `-F` option is designed to make the output of `lsof` easy to parse.

Iterating over these and removing the field identifiers is trivial.

```
#!/bin/bash
c=-1
while read -r line
do
    case $line in
        f*)
            fds[pids[c]]+=${line:1}" "
            ;;
        n*)
            names[pids[c]]+=${line:1}" "
            ;;
        p*)
            pids[++c]=${line:1}
            ;;
    esac
done < <(lsof -F pfn -- /tmp/Flash*)

for ((i=0; i<=c; i++))
do
    for name in ${names[pids[i]]}
    do
        for fd in ${fds[pids[i]]}
        do
            echo "File: $name, Process ID: ${pids[i]}, File Descriptor: $fd"
        done
    done
done
```

Lines like this:

```
fds[pids[c]]+=${line:1}" "
```

accumulate file descriptors in a string stored in an array indexed by the PID. Doing this for file names will fail for filenames which contain spaces. That could be worked around if necessary.

The line is stripped of the leading field descriptor character by using a substring operator: `${line:1}` starts at position one and includes the rest of the string so it drops character zero.

The second loop is just a demo to show iterating over the arrays.

Comment: This is interesting...I appreciate showing how to use the built-in switch for lsof. Unfortunately, this script won't work since the file in /tmp is always deleted. Previously, you could just copy/paste the file, but now it is unlinked and the only way to retrieve it is through /proc. This is why I had to pipe lsof's output to grep. This allows the -F switch to print only the name (n parameter). But again, this is a great learning experience, and I thank you.

Comment: @JohnSmith: You could still use the `-F` option. Iterate over the output saving the "p" and "f" entries as you find them, when you find an "n" entry that you're looking for then you have what you need. If you find a new "p" entry before you find the "n" you're looking for, drop the previous one and continue. There are example AWK and Perl scripts included in the `lsof` distribution, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

```
var=$(lsof | awk '/Flash/{gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$4);print $2 FS $4};exit')
set -- $var
pid=$1
number=$2
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using: pid=$(lsof | grep Flash | awk '{print $2}')
file_num=$(lsof | grep Flash | awk '{print substr($4,1,2)}')

Comment: @Richard: please post your solution as an own answer, so it is better to find.

Answer (score 1):

Completed Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $1 ]; then
    #lsof | grep Flash | awk '{print $2}' also works for PID
    pid=$(pidof plugin-container)
    file_num=$(lsof -p $pid | grep /tmp/Flash | awk '{print substr($4,1,2)}')

    cp /proc/$pid/fd/$file_num ~/Downloads/"$1".flv
else
    echo "Please enter video name as argument."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using lsof because it takes too long (>30 seconds) to return the path. The below .bashrc line will work with vlc, mplayer, or whatever you put in and return the path to the deleted temp file in milliseconds.
`` flashplay () {
          vlc $(stat -c %N /proc/*/fd/* 2>&1|awk -F[\`\'] '/lash/{print$2}')
} ``

Comment: Wow, I like this for its speed. I changed vlc to cp and added a destination (usually dot). The only thing is that it copies all the files from /proc/pid/fd/, but I really want to filter only to the one file. See my answer above for the current form of the script.