# In GNU Grep or another standard bash command, is it possible to get a resultset from regex?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Consider the following:

```
var="text more text and yet more text"
echo $var | egrep "yet more (text)"
```

It should be possible to get the result of the regex as the string: `text`

However, I don't see any way to do this in bash with grep or its siblings at the moment.

In perl, php or similar regex engines:

```
$output = preg_match('/yet more (text)/', 'text more text yet more text');
$output[1] == "text";
```

Edit: To elaborate why I can't just multiple-regex, in the end I will have a regex with multiple of these (Pictured below) so I need to be able to get all of them. This also eliminates the option of using lookahead/lookbehind (As they are all variable length)

```
egrep -i "([0-9]+) +$USER +([0-9]+).+?(/tmp/Flash[0-9a-z]+) "
```

Example input as requested, straight from lsof (Replace $USER with "j" for this input data):

```
npviewer. 17875          j   11u      REG                8,8 59737848     524264 /tmp/FlashXXu8pvMg (deleted)
npviewer. 17875          j   17u      REG                8,8 16037387     524273 /tmp/FlashXXIBH29F (deleted)
```

The end goal is to `cp /proc/$var1/fd/$var2 ~/$var3` for every line, which ends up "Downloading" flash files (Flash used to store in /tmp but they drm'd it up)

So far I've got:

```
#!/bin/bash
regex="([0-9]+) +j +([0-9]+).+?/tmp/(Flash[0-9a-zA-Z]+)"

echo "npviewer. 17875          j   11u      REG                8,8 59737848     524264 /tmp/FlashXXYOvS8S (deleted)" |
sed -r -n -e " s%^.*?$regex.*?\$%\1 \2 \3%p " |
while read -a array
do
   echo /proc/${array[0]}/fd/${array[1]} ~/${array[2]}
done
```

It cuts off the first digits of the first value to return, and I'm not familiar enough with sed to see what's wrong.

End result for downloading flash 10.2+ videos (Including, perhaps, encrypted ones):

```
#!/bin/bash
lsof | grep "/tmp/Flash" | sed -r -n -e " s%^.+? ([0-9]+) +$USER +([0-9]+).+?/tmp/(Flash[0-9a-zA-Z]+).*?\$%\1 \2 \3%p " |
while read -a array
do
   cp /proc/${array[0]}/fd/${array[1]} ~/${array[2]}
done
```

Comment: Could you get us some example input to test this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pull fields/attributes from lsof (Linux command line)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061328/pull-fields-attributes-from-lsof-linux-command-line)

Comment: @J V: At the page linked by Dennis are some more solutions, one using `awk`, one using another outputformat of `lsof`. Have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: look at my other answer for a simpler bash-only solution.

---

So, here the **solution using `sed` to fetch the right groups and split them up**. You later still have to use bash to read them. (And in this way it only works if the groups themselves do not contain any spaces - otherwise we had to use another divider character and patch `read` by setting `$IFS` to this value.)

```
#!/bin/bash
USER=j
regex=" ([0-9]+) +$USER +([0-9]+).+(/tmp/Flash[0-9a-zA-Z]+) "


sed -r -n -e " s%^.*$regex.*\$%\1 \2 \3%p " |
while read -a array
do
   cp /proc/${array[0]}/fd/${array[1]} ~/${array[2]}
done
```

Note that I had to adapt your last regex group to allow uppercase letters, and added a space at the beginning to be sure to capture the whole block of numbers. Alternatively here a `\b` (word limit) would have worked, too.

Ah, I forget mentioning that you should pipe the text to this script, like this:

```
 ./grep-result.sh  < grep-result-test.txt
```

(provided your files are named like this). Instead you can add a `< grep-result-test` after the `sed` call (before the `|`), or prepend the line with `cat grep-result-test.txt |`.

---

**How does it work?**

- `sed -r -n` calls sed in extended-regexp-mode, and without printing anything automatically.
- `-e " s%^.*$regex.*\$%\1 \2 \3%p "` gives the sed program, which consists of a single `s` command.

  - I'm using `%` instead of the normal `/` as parameter separator, since `/` appears inside the regex and I don't want to escape it.
  - The regex to search is prefixed by `^.*` and suffixed by `.*$` to grab the whole line (and avoid printing parts of the rest of the line).

    Note that this `.*` grabs greedy, so we have to insert a space into our regexp to avoid it grabbing the start of the first digit group too.
  - The replacement text contains of the three parenthesed groups, separated by spaces.
  - the `p` flag at the end of the command says to print out the pattern space after replacement. Since we grabbed the whole line, the pattern space consists of only the replacement text.
- So, the output of sed for your example input is this:

  ```
  5 11 /tmp/FlashXXu8pvMg
  5 17 /tmp/FlashXXIBH29F
  ```

  This is much more friendly for reuse, obviously.
- Now we pipe this output as input to the while loop.

  - `read -a array` reads a line from standard input (which is the output from sed, due to our pipe), splits it into words (at spaces, tabs and newlines), and puts the words into an array variable.

    We could also have written `read var1 var2 var3` instead (preferably using better variable names), then the first two words would be put to `$var1` and `$var2`, with `$var3` getting the rest.
  - If `read` succeeded reading a line (i.e. not end-of-file), the body of the loop is executed:

    - `${array[0]}` is expanded to the first element of the array and similarly.
  - When the input ends, the loop ends, too.

Comment: All I've ever used sed for is replacing text, I've updated the question to reflect the actual requirements (A bit more complicated, you guessed right)

Comment: Ok. Could you explain what this is doing? (And where the text is input?)

Comment: Added current script to original post, works better than anything else here but something's wrong. The first variable is getting all but the last digit chopped off.

Comment: Excellent howto, now that I see the different delimiter the sed makes much more sense :)

Comment: If there always is a space before your digit-block, add it to the regexp (outside the `()`). I thought my `^.*?` took care of this, though.

Comment: Yes, with a ` ` starting the regexp it works. It shows that I didn't really look at the output :-/

Comment: No problem, you did pretty damn good :) Still curius about the bash binary regex operator. And why the non-greedy star still swallowed up the digits. But good enough as it is :D

Comment: @JV: `sed` doesn't do non-greedy. To `sed -r`, `.*?` means "any character zero or more times optionally" (which is redundant).

Comment: @Dennis: thanks for this remark, I changed my answer regarding this.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't possible using grep or another tool called from a shell prompt/script because a child process can't modify the environment of its parent process.  If you're using bash 3.0 or better, then you can use in-process regular expressions.  The syntax is perl-ish (=~) and the match groups are available via $BASH_REMATCH[x], where x is the match group.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I'm trying it out right now!

Comment: while an if statement shows the regex matches, `echo ${#BASH_REMATCH[*]}` returns 0. Something is wrong.

Comment: see elaboration by Paŭlo, he beat me to it :)  Paŭlo, I'd vote you up if I had the privs

Answer (score 1):

After creating my `sed`-solution, I also wanted to try the **pure-bash** approach suggested by Mark. It works quite fine, for me.

```
#!/bin/bash

USER=j
regex=" ([0-9]+) +$USER +([0-9]+).+(/tmp/Flash[0-9a-zA-Z]+) "

while read 
do
    if [[ $REPLY =~ $regex ]]
    then
        echo cp /proc/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/fd/${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ~/${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    fi
done
```

(If you upvote this, you should think about also upvoting Marks answer, since it is essentially his idea.)

The same as before: pipe the text to be filtered to this script.

---

**How does it work?**

- As said by Mark, the `[[ ... ]]` special conditional construct supports the binary operator `=~`, which interprets his right operand (after parameter expansion) as a extended regular expression (just as we want), and matches the left operand against this. (We have again added a space at front to avoid matching only the last digit.)
- When the regex matches, the `[[ ... ]]` returns 0 (= true), and also puts the parts matched by the individual groups (and the whole expression) into the array variable `BASH_REMATCH`.
- Thus, when the regex matches, we enter the `then` block, and execute the commands there.
- Here again `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` is an array-access to an element of the array, which corresponds to the first matched group. (`[0]` would be the whole string.)

Another note: Both my scripts accept multi-line input and work on every line which matches. Non-matching lines are simply ignored. If you are inputting only one line, you don't need the loop, a simple `if read ; then ...` or even `read && [[ $REPLY =~ $regex ]] && ...` would be enough.

Comment: Same thing for Bash regexes. They don't support non-greediness.

Comment: @Dennis: Ah, I've missed this `.+?` in the middle of the regex. Thanks. (I think in this case it does not really matther, since there never are two times `/tmp/Flash` on one line.)

Comment: This works but I can't see why `BASH_REMATCH` works here but not anywhere else I've tried it...

Comment: @J V: If you would post your try, we could have a look.

Comment: I have now added both my answers to my [github repository](https://github.com/ePaul/stackoverflow-examples/tree/master/bash-regex) for easier access.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$var" | pcregrep -o "(?<=yet more )text"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for your simple example, you can do this:

```
var="text more text and yet more text"
echo $var | grep -e "yet more text" | grep -o "text"
```